# Can Flutter remove the need for a mac to create IOS apps?

Tags: dart, flutter

So I've wanted to build both android and IOS apps and the other day I found flutter. I know that IOS requires a MacOS but flutter works on windows.

My question is, can I develop and publish IOS apps on a windows computer using flutter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

The documentation on their site (https://flutter.io/docs/deployment/ios) references using Xcode and having the regular Apple accounts set up. The only way to build iOS applications without a Mac is to use a cloud service (which would use a Mac, but wouldn't require *you* to have a Mac).

Comment: It requires a Mac to compile, but you can use a used Mac-mini for that or an online service. I think the question was more about whether a single code base can build apps for Mac desktop **and** Mac mobile.

Comment: No, @GünterZöchbauer, the question is about building iOS apps on Windows.

Comment: Looks like you're right and I misinterpreted the question. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: Just wanted to add that anyone getting a used Mac Mini (or any other older used Mac) should be careful - Xcode12 will NOT run on any older computer and if you have a project that uses Xcode12 then you'll be wasting money buying older computer. Xcode12 requires at least Catalina or Big Sur, both require a Mac with Metal Graphics card.

Comment: Sure, try this cloud service: https://codemagic.io/start/

Answer (score 2):

No - you need to publish to the AppStore from a MAC.  It will not work from a Windows machine.

Comment: You don't need to install from AppStore for OSX. I install most OS apps using homebrew which is unrelated to AppStore.

Comment: You need a mac to upload to the app store for iOS, you cant sign it from a windows machine.

Answer (score 2):

No , you need XCode for build in iOS . If you have. a MAC on a Cloud Service or a Virtual Machine with it you can compile it for iOS but for Publish to AppStore needed a license anyways you can get .ipa .

Comment: then what is flutter for if you need a mac?

Comment: Is the same for other Multplatforms Languages like Xamarin , the part for iOS needed a Mac OS always because the close ecosystem. I'm developing Flutter with my MAC and I can compile for Android or iOS . Flutter is for develop with the same language for iOS and Android so your code if any time you can get acmes to Mac OS , you can compile it .

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No

You need Xcode and thus a Mac to test, build and publish an iOS app.

Nonetheless you can use third party tools to access a Mac build machine from your windows operating system. There is utility called [Odevio](https://github.com/Odevio/Odevio-CLI) which you can install by installing it from the website:https://www.odevio.com.

Once Odevio is installed you need to configure it with your Apple developer account : https://odevio-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/6_configure_app_store_connect.html

Then you can start working on your ios version by creating a Configuration build.

Answer (score -3):

No actually it isn't possible.
But there is 1 more solution You can download McOS virtual machine but it would be very slow, recommended only if you have a powerful computer

Comment: You can't run MacOS on non-Apple hardware.

Comment: @JJJ yes you can.

Comment: @MuhammadSaqib you technically can, but it's against Apple's license agreement, which I think is what JJJ meant.

Comment: @Adam Burley True, but you can legally run a "MacOS virtual machine" on a Mac. We have three Mac Pro towers running native Windows, and then we run MacOS guest virtual machines on all three. All three have some external hardware connected which only has windows driver, but all three also need to do iOS development hence the whole hoopla. So all of you guys are right.